# grails - composite key, Hibernate mapping Exception

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, composite-key

The following Domain class gives this Mapping Exception on startup:

> *Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested*                  *exception is
>   org.hibernate.MappingException:Foreignkey*
>   (FKA9FB5C607D60EAE9:person_examschedule [testingcenter_examschedule_id
>   dummy_table,testing_center_exam_schedule_testing_center_id,testing_center_exam_schedule_exam_schedule_id]))
>   must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key
>   (testingcenter_examschedule [testingcenter_id,examschedule_id])

```
class TestingCenterExamSchedule implements Serializable{

Long testingCenterId
ExamSchedule examSchedule
TestingCenter testingCenter   
int bufferedSlots

static transients = ['testingCenter']

static constraints = {
    examSchedule nullable: false
    testingCenter nullable: false
    testingCenterId nullable: false
    bufferedSlots nullable:false
}

static mapping = {
    table 'testingcenter_examschedule'
    version false
    id composite: ['testingCenterId','examSchedule']
    testingCenterId column: 'testingcenter_id'
    examSchedule column: 'examschedule_id'
    bufferedSlots column: 'buffered_slots'

}
```

and this is my another domain class which is also has a composite key

```
class RegistrantTestingCenterExamSchedule implements Serializable {

Registrant registrant
TestingCenterExamSchedule testingCenterExamSchedule

static constraints = {
    registrant nullable: false
    testingCenterExamSchedule nullable: false
}

static mapping = {
    table 'person_examschedule'
    version: false
    id composite: ['registrant', 'testingCenterExamSchedule']
    columns {
        registrant column: 'person_id'
        testingCenterExamSchedule column: ['testingcenter_examschedule_id', 'dummy_table']
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time to solve this problem, and I want to make this work because of my existing schema, can anyone tell me what's the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Is this question answered yet?

Answer (score 0):

In TestingCenterExamSchedule you've declared testingCenter as a transient property, I wonder if that's not causing issues with the GORM mapping?  At any rate you seem to be unnecessarily mapping columns, many of those you've defined should get created automatically, even if you're mapping to an existing/legacy table schema.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the [same issue I'm facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563283/gorm-doesnt-handle-mapping-of-associations-which-have-a-further-association-in).

Brass tacks: pretty sure it's a bug with GORM-Hibernate, [which I've logged here](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/660).

Workaround would be to strip off the association mappings and create getters and setters which manually load your associations for you. This wouldn't necessarily be sufficient for all use cases.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯